# loaded script does not appear in global context

Tags: requirejs, aurelia

I am attempting to load a script in one of my models:

```
attached(){
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/lib/zxcvbn/dist/zxcvbn.js',
  dataType: 'script',
  cache: true
}).done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log('loaded script');
});
```

}

The `done` callback is hit however the export `zxcvbn` is not available in the global context.

The exact same code run in a plain html page (i.e. not aurelia) works fine (zxcvbn *is* available in the global context)

I know this is not the recommended way of loading an external JS file in aurelia however the script is quite large and is only required in one spot in my app.
The docs for [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) state:

> zxcvbn detects and supports CommonJS (node, browserify) and AMD (RequireJS). In the absence of those, it adds a single function zxcvbn() to the global namespace.

My aurelia app is using RequireJS; If it isn't loaded into the global namespace where is it loaded and how can i reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you give, the `zxcvbn` detects that there's an AMD loader present (RequireJS) and calls `define` to register itself as an AMD module.

Since you already have RequireJS on the page, you can replace your jQuery call with a call to `require`, and pass the full path:

```
require(['/lib/zxcvbn/dist/zxcvbn.js'], function (zxcvbn) {
  // Do something with zxcvbn ...
});
```

Since the script registers itself as an AMD module, the parameter `zxcvbn` will hold the module's value.

Note that when you pass a path that begins with a forward slash, RequireJS uses the path as-is: this bypasses your RequireJS configuration (e.g. `baseUrl`, `paths`, `map` are not applied, etc.), and RequireJS does not add a `.js` extension, so it needs to have the extension.